# How to implement a message queue system using Samza and Kafka?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, queue, webhooks, apache-samza

I have to build a queing system that takes in events, and redirects them to multiple consumers. I havent understood how I can implement such a queing system that distributes events to consumers using Samza and Kafka. Please provide resources